# Checkstyle for XML, text, properties file formats

Tags: checkstyle

Can checkstyle be configured to check xml, text, properties file formats. I have a requirment wherein I need to check for certain keywords in java, xml, text etc. file formats. For e.g. if in a text file the text "danger" appears, then I need to inform the user that the text danger appears in this line, please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Checkstyle has a regular expression check that can check for any keyword for you.  But I don't know how to get it to check non-java files.  I think a better tool for this job is grep.

Answer (score 0):

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) can at least check XML. For anything else you may want to consider [writing a plug-in](http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/write-sonarqube-plug-in/) for [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/).