# Static format checker for xml files using Maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, code-formatting, checkstyle

i'm using Maven as a build tool and Checkstyle to check that files conform to the agreed coding style.

The problem is that i also want to check formatting in XML files too, just simple indentation checks, but checkstyle doesn't support it.

I just can't find a tool that can do this simple checks and integrate with Maven.

Any ideas ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750585/checkstyle-for-xml-text-properties-file-formats

Comment: So, there's no tool that does this ?

Comment: The link says PMD can do it. https://pmd.github.io/ I don't know if it checks everything you need, but PMD can check XML stuff.

Comment: Right, but not formatting. In fact, it only has 1 rule for XML that checks the XML CDATA section https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.6.0/pmd_rules_xml.html

Comment: Checkstyle can support any language you can provide a parser for, but you would have to build up all the classes surrounding it yourself (Parser, Node class, abstract check class, and XML Indentation check). I started some, but never finished or put it up anywhere.

Comment: @rveach right, so there's no existing tool that does this.

Comment: @hugo-palma none that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search offers this:
https://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/check-format-mojo.html

> Full name:
>    org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0.2:check-format
>
> Description:
>    An XML indentation check over a set of files.

Though I have not used it myself.